# How Can I send ConfirmWaitTime in the PKIMessage?

Tags: java, x509certificate, pki

I am new to PKI. Working with `Certified Management Protocol`. I want to send  `ConfirmWaitTime` with PKIMessage.

I have added a new parameter confirmWaitTime in PKIXCertResponse.java and sending it as int value.

So in the client that object we are extracting PKIXCertResponse (CertRepMessage) as below

```
PKIMessage pkiMessage = //actual response
CertRepMessage certRep = CertRepMessage.getInstance(pkiMessage .getBody().getContent());
```

So here we are getting error something similar to 'Unexpected ASN1Integer'.

Same error when i try from client **openssl-cmp** throws error that 'Unexpected ASN1Integer' due to this additional integer parameter.

How can I pass this additional parameter in the response?
Do I need to pass it as an object in the Header as mention in RFC?  If yes how can I generate this object and attach to the header?
`confirmWaitTime OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= {id-it 14}
         ConfirmWaitTimeValue ::= GeneralizedTime`

Please suggest me the correct way to send this ConfirmWaitTime in the PKIMessage